# Yii Model: Username rule allow a-z_-

Tags: php, yii

How can I make a rule at Yii Framework to allow only characters a-z, underline and dash in username field?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to use the `match`/`pattern` rule outlined in the [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh17):

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('username', 'required'),
        array(
            'username',
            'match', 'not' => true, 'pattern' => '/[^a-zA-Z_-]/',
            'message' => 'Invalid characters in username.',
        ),
    );
}
```

This, *untested code*, will require the `username` field to contain data and then validate that it doesn't contain a character not in the accepted-character list (a-z, underscore, and dash).

Comment: Can You also provide yii2 version?

Comment: for yii2 just replace array() with [] e.g
[ 'company_name', 'match', 'not' => true, 'pattern' => '/[^a-zA-Z_-]/', 'message' => 'Invalid characters', ],